# Question on first differentiate Equation

Tags: calculus

How can Diﬀerentiate the following function please help ? 
1) $u=e^{\frac{-1}y}$
my answer is 
$u=-e^\frac{-1}{y}$ .Is my solution is correct please ?

Comment: u need to use the chain rule

Answer (score 1):

$u=e^{\frac{-1}{y}}$

then $u'=e^{\frac{-1}{y}}* (\frac1{y^2})$

because differential of $e^y$ is $e^y$ but if you have $e^{f(y)}$ then its differentiation is $e^{f(y)}*f'(y)$ this is due to chain rule. here $f(y)=\frac{-1}{y}$ and its derivative is $\frac1{y^2}$